# Microsoft form Recognizer 2.1

Tags: forms, azure, azure-cognitive-services

Using the standard azure service layout I have a requirement to get the text style font colour, all my text styles are coming out as shown below, need to distinguish text font colour in form

"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 0.819
}

Answer (score 1):

This `style` property is not aimed currently to provide the kind of details you are looking for. It is only here to inform about "handwritten" vs "other" style.

See documentation:

- [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/concept-layout?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#text) talking about what "style" is about
- [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.formrecognizer.style?view=azure-dotnet-preview&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365) is the documentation about `Style` class in the dotnet SDK of Form Recognizer: it will lead to this `TextStyle` class ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.formrecognizer.models.textstyle?view=azure-dotnet-preview&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365))

The information you are looking for are not provided by this service.